# NextJS + Heroku: env variables not loading

Tags: javascript, heroku, next.js, dotenv

I'm using NextJS and Heroku.

At the index - First load returns the data I fetched in getInitialProps, but in a regular function I get an error message because the env vars are missing.

When I go to a different page I get the same error, but when I refresh I can see the data fetched at getInitialProps. But again, in a regular function I get an error for the missing env variables.

Locally it works.
I tried dotenv-webpack but it doesn't help.
I added the config vars in Heroku.

Any ideas?

this is my next.config.js file:

```
const { parsed: localEnv } = require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    //target: 'serverless',
    webpack(config) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv))
        config.node = {fs: "empty"};
        config.plugins = config.plugins || []

        config.plugins = [
            ...config.plugins,

            // Read the .env file
            new Dotenv({
                path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
                systemvars: true
            })
        ]

        return config
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        ADDRESS: process.env.ADDRESS,
        API_TOKEN: process.env.API_TOKEN,
        INFURA_API_KEY: process.env.INFURA_API_KEY
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting your environment variables? You probably _shouldn't_ be using a `.env` file in production. Heroku [natively supports configuration via the environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: I used the Heruko dashboard option and used it as seen in the code - for example: process.env.ADDRESS

Comment: But as I said, the code uses the environment variables on server side rendering (first load of index and in general, every page after refresh), so the problem is probably not the way I set the config vars. On a regular function (triggered by a button click), I get a message for the missing variables and also after I navigate to a different page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got an answer in next.js github page: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6533

I tried a few different ways to solve it that collided.

Setting the environment vars with `dotenv-webpack` didn't work for me. What did work was setting `env` in `next.config.js` like this:

```
const { parsed: localEnv } = require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    webpack(config) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv))
        config.node = {fs: "empty"};
        config.plugins = config.plugins || []

        config.plugins = [
            ...config.plugins,
        ]

        return config
    },
    env: {
        ADDRESS: '0xd6F75293ec795',
        API_TOKEN: 'YUBKzlbA2eFmNbkzk',
        INFURA_API_KEY: '97eb10aac61799f9e865',
        MNEMONIC: 'my not so secret for testing password',
    }
}
```

Comment: Phew, glad to hear :)

Comment: this helped me achieve deployment. a doff of the cap to you all. x

Comment: How do you make this environment specific?

Comment: @Blueboye - In the docs they mention that this is a Node.js module and not a JSON file (" It gets used by the Next server and build phases, and not included in the browser build. "). So you should try using next/constants to define the 'phase' you want. " 'phase' is the current context in which the configuration is loaded. "

Comment: @KarinC  Aren't you exposing you secrets with this approach? Unless if you are saying that you don't version control your `next.config.js`, which I doubt given the custom configs you have there.

Comment: @iamcastelli You're right. I added it to gitignore. It's a small project I made, so I don't change it often.

Comment: To prevent hardcoding your values like you are doing here, you could write a config module at buildtime, and import that module here.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me (in next.config.js):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

module.exports = {
  env: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  }
}
```

This makes API_URL available on both the client and the server, on development and production environments.